# Disable cPanel Apache access logging by cPanel account itself?

Tags: apache, cpanel, logging

Solutions I found through Google to disable access logging of a particular cPanel account seems to be either editing httpd.conf or having access to WHM.

Is it possible for the cPanel account itself to disable its Apache access logging without any server / root administrator level privileges? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to disable or change the access logging configuration from within cPanel, or using .htaccess files or any other tricks - this can only be done with server administration privileges, not a single cPanel user privileges.

Greater control over the logging would be a great feature to add into cPanel, though I can't personally think of any reason why I would disable it for any website. If disabling the logging is important you may need to consider setting up and managing your own VPS since all ISP's will generally require some level of logging to help with troubleshooting and monitoring systems health, even if they are not required to keep logs by law.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to disable the access logging, you will need access to httpd.conf file. This is possible only if you have root privileges. I won't be possible to edit these values with cPanel access.